# Reusing fields/properties in case classes

Tags: json, scala, case-class, scala-macros

I have huge json objects, which I extract to case classes using liftweb.json library. Basically, many of them contain a lot of common fields, having only 1 or 2 specific ones. Any possible way to deal with the common fields without repeating them? (there are around 20, it is ugly and tedious).

Maybe macros are of help here?

EDIT: After closely looking at macros, it seems that a solution could be achieved using macro-paradise compiler plugin and macro annotations. But it seems too heavy and fragile for a real project.

Comment: Using a specific case class for the most common fields? Like `case class Message1(common: CommonFields, specificField1: Int, ...)`, Of course then you'll need custom serializer/deserializers.

Comment: I'd not rather mess with serializers. I just understood that I have had this problem with repeating tens of properties more than once. And I decided to try to find a solution. Can it be done using macros? Taking one case class as a template and adding fields to it producing new case class.

Comment: Better using macro only for boilerplate code, not for your domain model classes. Case class convenience consists mostly in their simplicity and availability for source code analysis, IDEs, etc. Using macros, beside non portable (see Scala 3 plans), could lower code readability if used in core domain classes. In a similar case (with protobuf instead of json) in the past I used generated source code, and used macro only to bind the relevant generated classes to the IO classes in a transparent way.

Comment: Well, I understand but the tediousness of the issue appeals to invent something.